# "Неснижающейся" или "не снижающейся"?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно писать "в связи с не снижающейся угрозой"?

Comment: Фразу целиком приведите. Без этого сказать наверняка нельзя. Кстати,  это у вас про неё или про него? Если про него, то писать в любом случае надо "не()снижающ**и**йся". А если про неё , то "неснижающейся", но в косвенных падежах.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> ...в связи с "не снижающейся" угрозой...

Здесь скорее всего слитно, поскольку не видно зависимых слов и/или противопоставления. Но все равно: по такому куску - гадание на кофейной гуще,  Неужели так трудно всю фразу написать?!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: в связи с неснижающейся (постоянной)  угрозой".

**Пояснение**

**Одиночные** причастия по значению близки к прилагательным и пишутся слитно с приставкой НЕ.

Также следует обратить внимание на то, что прилагательные **в роли определения  в предложно-падежных формах** пишутся, как правило, слитно, например: в **небольшой** комнате, сравнить: комната **небольшая** и комната **не большая** (два варианта).

Пример:

Из приказа министерства: **В связи с неснижающейся  угрозой** совершения террористических и диверсионных актов на объектах топливно-энергетического комплекса...